# I can not call an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, loopback

I can not call an array of objects in my interface,  I leave my Angular interface, and then I have to call it in the complement in the typeScript, but I do not understand how to call the array if it does not have a name, and if I can put it name, please explain me!

**Vehiculo-interface.ts**

```
export interface vehiculointerface {
    placa?: string,
    [index:number]: { Ubicacion ?: string, Nombre ?: string }
    id?: string
}
```

**detalles-placa.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/post.service';
import { ActivatedRoute,Params } from '@angular/router';
import { vehiculointerface } from '../Models/Vehiculo-interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-detalles-placa',
    templateUrl: './detalles-placa.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./detalles-placa.component.css']
})
export class DetallesPlacaComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private post: PostService, route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    private vehiculo: vehiculointerface = {
        placa: "",
        { Ubicacion: "", Nombre: ""},

        index() = { Ubicacion: "", Nombre: "" }
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I can not call an object array declared on my interface `[index:number]: {Ubicacion ?: string, Nombre ?: string}` I can not call an object array declared in my interface `Vehiculo-interface.ts` this is the one I need in `detalles-placa.component.ts`

Comment: Perhaps others can confirm - but to me it looks like you would need something like this... [0]:{Ubicacion: "", Nombre ?: ""} Both Ubicacion and Nombre are optional because of the `?` .. So you could effectively have one, or the other or even [0]{} in its place.

Comment: If you want an array of objects, why don't you use... an array type? `Array<{Ubicacion?: string, Nombre?: string}>`? Also, Be consistent and respect naming conventions: class and interface names start with an uppercase letter. Properties start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @JGFMK This code let's say that if it serves me, but I think it only brings me a single value of all the ones I have in the array and I need to bring it all, I'm really new to Angular and I'm doing this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PU6eItWLFSY&lc=Ugzre02AXU1NOqAdIyh4AaABAg.8oPZDMc3GVg8oQc12gEkR0 , at minute 3:29 is where he makes this fix and then calls the property at 5:13 and can not call the array as it should be

Comment: I would really recommend going through the Angular documentation - the heroes example was very information. Then take a look at the free Angular University videos on Youtube. If you like that and want to learn more they have more paid content. I can thoroughly recommend them. But for now you want to use something like *ngFor in the markup. https://angular.io/tutorial https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3cEGKhg3OERn-ihVsJcb7A/playlists

Comment: I watched the video link you posted and don't see anything that looks like your indexed property??

Answer (score 0):

This syntax:

```
[index:number]: { Ubicacion ?: string, Nombre ?: string }
```

Is an **index signature** defining an indexable type. And indexable type is a type that we can "index into".

You can read more about them here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

And here is the example from the docs:

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

So it is not defining a specific named property, but rather providing a way to "index into" your type.

**Using the indexer alone**

With your structure, this worked for me:

```
  private vehiculo: vehiculointerface = [{
    Ubicacion: "some string",
    Nombre: "some id"
  },
  {
    Ubicacion: "other string",
    Nombre: "other id"
  }]
```

I'm treating it as an array of objects. (Not sure why you'd have an indexer property for information that wasn't meant to be processed as an array?)

You can then access it in the template as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of vehiculo">
  {{ item.Ubicacion}}; {{ item.Nombre}}
</div>
```

**Using the indexer with other members**

I had not really worked with an indexer with other members, so I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. But something like this *also* worked for me:

```
  private vehiculo: vehiculointerface = {
    placa: "some string",
    id: "some id"
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vehiculo["some index"] = {
      Ubicacion: "some string",
      Nombre: "some id"
    }
    this.vehiculo["other index"] = {
      Ubicacion: "other string",
      Nombre: "other id"
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.vehiculo));
  }
```

Notice how the non-indexer members are defined independent of the indexer.

The above code defines the basic properties of the interface, then uses the indexer to set additional values.

The resulting structure looks like this:

```
{
 "placa":"some string",
 "id":"some id",
 "some index":{"Ubicacion":"some string","Nombre":"some id"},
 "other index":{"Ubicacion":"other string","Nombre":"other id"}
}
```

I then accessed it in the template using this code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of vehiculo2 | keyvalue">
  {{ item.key}}; {{ item.value}}
</div>
```

But note that the value for the indexed properties are displayed as `[object, Object]` because they are of type `{ Ubicacion ?: string, Nombre ?: string }`

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-indexer-deborahk

Comment: the truth remembers that to consult the information by means of an API REST and therefore ... it does not work to me